# How to change Virtuemart Top Level Category Meta-Title and Meta-Description?

Tags: virtuemart, seo

I have created a menu structure to show my products like this:

```
TOP LEVEL CATEGORY
  -> PRODUCT CATEGORY A
    -> SUBCATEGORY A
    -> SUBCATEGORY B
  -> PRODUCT CATEGORY B
```

...and so on.
I know that I can change the `meta-title` and `meta-description` of each category from Virtuemart, but I cannot see how to change them for the top level category, since it overwrites the Joomla menu `Browse Page Title` and `Meta Description`.

These forum posts mention that it is not possible:
[Browser Page Title for Top Level Category](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=129593.0)
[VirtueMart Categories Layout: Empty Title tag](https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=91800.15)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not really a discovery, but since I couldn't find much information online, I thought I could share the thought, to save someone a couple of minutes.

The only way to currently change this (Virtuemart version 3.0.14, Joomla 3.5.1),
 is to **create your own top level category**. If you had this category structure:

```
DEFAULT TOP LEVEL CATEGORY
  -> APPLES
  -> BANANAS
```

You should simply do this:

```
DEFAULT TOP LEVEL CATEGORY
  -> FRUITS
    -> APPLES
    -> BANANAS
```

And build your menu structure around the Fruits category, instead of using the top level category.